# Strange 7-character directories in Appdata/Local folder on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have ~1500 directories in my temp folder (`C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp`), all are empty.

And have weird 7-character long names that always alternate like consonant-vowel-consonant.

Here's a sample of some of the folder names:

```
Baboteq
Bagames
Bahofuz
Bajokuw
Banuhan
Banujot
Baqafek
Baquhon
Barybum
Basaxad
Basykum
Baxenur
Beboxup
Bedizyk
Bedyneg
Begarer
Begipek
Bekemun
Bekifog
Bekizid
Bemonef
Bepopip
Beqazab
Beqenad
Beqikix
Berewen
Betosoh
Betygun
Bexexed
Bexyvaf
Bibydyz
Bigibih
Bijavik
Bipibug
Biqubyk
Bivezik
Bivusuf
Biwujyx
Bixameg
Bixipim
Bixiwit
Bizugef
Bofikoc
Bofuxek
Bojybov
Boragup
Bosadog
Boturuc
Bowucuk
Bubobep
Bubymik
Bucodyj
Bufatuz
Bufytop
Bulibot
Buruqam
Busaciq
Butaquw
Buxabyl
Buxakuc
Bybyryf
Byconuv
Bydutoz
Byfysox
Bygaqaw
Byjecyg
Byjudyd
Byjymif
Bykoleh
Bykunev
Bynizaq
Bypymip
Byqohaf
Byqunag
```

... you get the idea

What is creating these?

Comment: It is likely we can know what! However, are they created at the same time?

Comment: they've been created since March last year, which is when I got the computer.

Comment: Just had another look and it looks like they are all created at the same date, about once a month.

Comment: So it's some form of dodgy software! I would guess. I'm not saying virus or anything evil, just buggy! You'll need to look through MSCONFIG, the task scheduler and uninstall things which you don't fully trust

Comment: Mmm. I mean, I didn't see any scheduled task that had run at the last date where one of these "batches" of folders appeared, and there's no services or processes running that I don't know, or didn't install myself. I'm not particularly worried, more curious than anything.